# When there is nothing to be $_REQUEST

Tags: php, request

I would like to do the following but fail.

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];

if (/* nothing to be requested*/) {
    echo "<button>Log In</button><button>Sign Up</button>";
} else {
    /* logged in, check if the user is an admin or not */
    if ( /* he is admin */ ) {
    echo "<button>Admin</button><button>Logout</button>";
    } else {
    /* then he is just a normal user */
    echo "<button>Logout</button>";
    }
}
```

Original code:

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
if (!$user_id) {
    echo "<button>Log In</button><button>Sign Up</button>"
} else {
    $check_sql = "SELECT admin from users where user_id = {'$user_id'}";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $check_sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result);
        if ($rows['admin'] == 1) {
        echo "<button>Admin</button><button>Log Out</button>";
        } else {
        echo "<button>Log Out</button>";
    }
}
```

When there is a user_id to be $_REQUEST, the code works fine. But just fail when there is nothing to be $_REQUEST. Would you please help?

Thanks very much!

Comment: put this: if( empty($user_id) )

Comment: use if (empty($user_id)) { }

Comment: use this  if (!isset($user_id) )

Comment: Thanks very much bfahmi and jothi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that you code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. This is very serious. You should be using parameterized queries or escaping the `$user_id` variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Also note that your code may be vulnerable to someone setting the `$user_id` themselves, thus possibly getting admin privileges when they shouldn't. This is because you are using `$_REQUEST` and those values can be set by the request in manners you might not anticipate. Alternatively, you can store the `user_id` in `$_SESSION`.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

As far as the check for `$user_id`, it should be:

```
if(empty($user_id))
```

You might also want to trim the `$user_id`.

If you are using PHP < 5.5:

```
$user_id= trim($user_id);
if(empty($user_id)
```

If you are using PHP >= 5.5

```
if(empty(trim($user_id))
```

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Thanks very much Josh K, the injection attacks thing will be my next step. Thanks again!